# AngularJS + Spring Security + Weblogic 12

Tags: angularjs, spring-security, weblogic12c

I am creating a Login page using AngularJs and Spring Security4, using 
https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/single. 
Everything works good, so far except when I use below code in ***hello.js***

```
var headers = credentials ? {authorization : "Basic "
        + btoa(credentials.username + ":" + credentials.password)
    } : {};
```

It's sent a 401, which is correct but it also sent Response header - 
***WWW-Authenticate:Basic realm="weblogic"***

Which opens a popup. How can I sent the 401 but remove the header.

Note: I already use below code as mention in the article
`$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following in **config.xml**

```
<security-configuration>
<enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials>false</enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials>
</security-configuration>
```